# rails missing assets cause missing templates error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I am working on a rails site that is pretty much only being used for the rails asset pipeline to serve angular and css. I am noticing when an image is missing, it results in a very large backtrace that doesn't damage the app, but is causing errbit to freak out. the error looks like this:

```
Started GET "/assets/uploads/images/persona/photo/headshot/40/cropped_bc0e064e-73e4-495b-b916-5d6b4b95b464.jpg" 
 for ::1 at 2016-07-14 12:22:39 -0700
Processing by SinglePageApplicationController#angular as JPEG
  Parameters: {"path"=>"assets/uploads/images/persona/photo/headshot/40/
 cropped_bc0e064e-73e4-495b-b916-5d6b4b95b464"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1ms

ActionView::MissingTemplate - Missing template layouts/application with {:locale=>[:en], 
:formats=>[:jpeg], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :slim, :coffee]}. 
 Searched in: * "/Users/username/project/app/views"
```

does anyone know what a good fix for this would be? this doesn't damage the actual app at all, but I've done some searching and nothing has fixed it.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: You made the request as `format` set to `JPEG`, look the log *Processing by SinglePageApplicationController#angular as JPEG*. Check the code which is making the call and fix there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure it out by adding this in the `application_controller`

```
rescue_from ActionView::MissingTemplate do |exception|
end
```

and now there's no errors or stacktraces :)